# How passing colors in props using backtick with tailwindcss

Tags: react-props

I'm trying to pass colors in props by using backtick in tailwindcss but it doesn't work, nothing happen...
In fact, I have no idea on what syntaxe should I use in the component for express the color by using tailwind, maybe just: "text-blue-500" ?
My code is the following :

<Icon className={`h-14 ${bg={col}}`}

How should I manage the component part ?

Really need a help, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the props incorrectly. Classnames that you are passing should be props, hence, you should do something like
`` <Icon className={`h-14 ${bg={col}}`} /> `` instead of `<Icon className={h-14 ${bg={col}}} />`.

But `tailwind` recommends you send full classname instead of partially dynamic ones ie `bg-red-200` instead of `bg-${col}`

So you should do something like this

`` <Icon className={`h-14 ${condition ? "bg-yellow-400" : "bg-red-200"}`} /> ``

where `condition` would be a `boolean`